# SQL multiple counts with multiple statements win different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am looking for a way to get multiple counts from a table using one query. I want to get the total of every USER_level (there are only 3) that have used a specific terminal and where the status is granted

Table

```
CARD    TERMINAL        TRANSIT_DATE        STATUS  STR_DIRECTION   USER_Level
12      D1      2019-12-02 07:12:30.000     Granted Exit            level1
10      D1      2019-12-02 13:22:29.000     Granted Exit            level3
11      D2      2019-12-02 17:09:05.000     Granted Exit            level1
17      D2      2019-12-03 09:58:22.000     deny    Entry           level2
19      D3      2019-12-03 12:17:29.000     Granted Entry           level2
32      D3      2019-12-03 13:48:33.000     Granted Exit            level1
20      D2      2019-12-04 10:36:22.000     Granted Exit            level3
11      D3      2019-12-07 22:01:41.000     Granted Exit            level1
15      D2      2019-12-09 11:12:16.000     Granted Exit            level2
14      D3      2019-12-10 06:32:22.000     Granted Entry           level2
12      D2      2019-12-10 10:31:26.000     Granted Exit            level1
39      D2      2019-12-11 06:42:08.000     Granted Exit            level3
12      D2      2019-12-11 09:32:13.000     Granted Exit            level1
11      D3      2019-12-11 12:44:36.000     Granted Exit            level2
56      D2      2019-12-12 06:48:33.000     Granted Exit            level2
78      D2      2019-12-12 12:03:23.000     Granted Entry           level1
66      D3      2019-12-10 12:16:54.000     Granted Exit            level3
22      D2      2019-12-09 16:02:02.000     Granted Exit            level1
```

Example would look like this result

```
TERMINAL    level 1  level 2 level 3
D1          1               1 
D2          6        2      2
D3          2        3      1
...
```

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are completely different RDBMS, what are you *really* using? What have you tried, and why didn't it work?

Comment: Tag your question properly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this, note that if more terminals are present, you must add them to the query.

```
select terminal, 
       sum(case when user_level = 'level1' then 1 else 0 end) as level1, 
       sum(case when user_level = 'level2' then 1 else 0 end) as level2,
       sum(case when user_level = 'level3' then 1 else 0 end) as level3
from yourTable
    where status = 'Granted' 
      and transit_date > your_initial_date
group by terminal
```

Hope it helps!